# How to delete a specific string from an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

I need a function that receives an array of pointers to strings and it's size.
Then it should seek for those strings which occur in the array more than once - then I have to delete them and realloc the array. 
Function should return new size of the array.
I'm trying to solve this, and not sure what`s wrong.

I want to move each string, that I want to delete, to the end of the array and then delete it, but not sure when the "realloc" should happen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int DeleteString(char** tab, int n){
    char* check=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    int deleted;
    int i,j,g,h;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        strcpy(check, tab[i]);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(strcmp(check, tab[j]) == 0){     
                deleted++;
                char* temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
                for(h=j;h<n-1;h++){
                    strcpy(temp, tab[h+1]);
                    strcpy(tab[h+1], check);
                    strcpy(tab[h], temp);       
                }
            }

            if(deleted>0){
                realloc(tab, sizeof(char*)*(n-deleted));
            }
        }
    }
    return n-deleted;
}
```

For now there is "Segmentation fault" error

Comment: `deleted` is unitialized. That is enough to invoke Undefined Behaviour. You should declare `int deleted = 0;`. And you fail to free the allocated strings whick leaks memory. BTW, you have no reason to allocate memory in that function...

Comment: Isn't it better to just copy only the strings that you want to a new array and return that? It will take up more memory but it will be much easier to write and I'd say also faster.

Comment: you say _from now there's "Segmentation fault" error_. Where is from now?  where do you get that error?

Comment: Why have you tagged the question `multidimensional-array`.  You don't have any multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, your code contains numerous problems, because you failed to observe some major rules of C language:

- every non static variable shall be initialized (what about `deleted`?)
- any object that was malloced shall be freed (what about `check` and `temp`.)
- never change something that was passed as an input parameter to a function, or do not expect the change to be visible on return (`tab` has to be considered here because of next line).
- allways assign the result of `realloc` because it can be different from the input pointer (`realloc(tab, sizeof(char*)*(n-deleted));`).

The first one is probably the cause of the segmentation fault because as `deleted` is unitialized its value is just undeterminated. But all problems should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, now I only have issue with the algorithm but memory`s fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the SEGMENTATION FAULT is  tab[0] store the address of the variable which stores the actual string.
Here  tab[i] is in for loop,hence when it tries to fetch tab[1] itself memory error.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    strcpy(check, tab[i]);...}
```

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
 char *foo = "something";
 char **ptr2;
 ptr2 = &foo;
 printf("check = %s", *ptr2); 
 for(int i=0;i<9;i++){  
   printf(" check = %c",  ptr2[i]);
 }
```

Output

```
check = something check = 4check = �check = pcheck =
```

Actally it is an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't forget to initialise variables like `deleted`, as it has been said in other answers.

Next, you are supposed to free memory (as you are deleting items) and you only call `malloc(3)`).  That seems a little counter-common sense, doesn't it?

Third, you make a lot of string copying in the loops, while it should be more efficient just to move pointers up, so you don't need to realloc the string elements and copy the cell contents (by the way, are you sure those strings will be feed to the function as `malloc()`d strings?  I will assume that as you do)

Fourth, consider sorting the array first, so all the similar strings will be adjacent in the array.  This has a cost `O(n*log(n))` that, appended to the delete next string if equal (with cost `O(n)`) makes total cost `O(n*(log(n)+1))` or `O(n*log(n))` and not `O(n^2)` which is your actual cost)

Once sorted, only the strings deleted should be `free(3)`d, the pointers moved back to the start of the array as holes get appearing, and finally(when all is finished) you can just `realloc(3)` the array of pointers (only once, not at every pass through the loop)

Remaking the example is out of the scope of this answer, as it looks actually some school exercise.  Sorry for that.  I'm sure that the other hints will help you to retry the exercise with more success.

And think: thinking before writing is how one succeeds in this job.